# How to filter posts by author on edit.php

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, filtering

Let's suppose the user visits the page of

```
http://mywpsite/wp-admin/edit.php?author=john-doe
```

Let's suppose there is an author with the name of `'John Doe'` and the given author has three posts. Yet, when I visit the page, I see an empty grid, as if there were no posts created by this author.

I would like to search for posts created by the given user. Based on my research, I can see that people are claiming that something like this should work:

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {

    if($query->is_admin) {

        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

[Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-authors-posts-in-admin-panel-instead-of-all-posts).

However, here the author's ID is expected as input, yet, I do not know how to get the author's id by the slug of `'john-doe'`.

How can I get the ID of the author by slug and search for posts based on that ID?

EDIT:

This is one failed try, based on NATH's comment:

```
function wpshock_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ((is_admin()) && (isset($_GET["author"])) && (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z_0-9]/i', $_GET["author"]))) {
        $query->set("author_name", $_GET["author"]);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpshock_search_filter');
```

The query still returns no elements. I have `var_dump`ed `$query` and seen that `$query->query["author"]` has the textual problem, which is a potential problem. Also, `$query->tax_query` contains data related to author. I am sorry if this question is worthy of down-votes, I thought others might be confused by Wordpress's database handling as well and thus this question might be useful. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: If you already have the `user_nicename` you can use `$query->set('author_name', $user_nicename);` instead of getting the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress provides an `author_name` query variable to you. You can use the following by default:

```
http://mywpsite/wp-admin/edit.php?author_name=john-doe
```

Read more about public query variables [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

`get_user_by('slug','john-doe');`

EDIT : 
From this you can get author object and you can carry forward with your code.

[Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

Comment: Thank you, Harsh. I have tried your answer, but unfortunately, I still got an empty result set. I believe the query is already polluted by the author value received as get parameter. I am a noob in Wordpress, so I might miss something really simple.

Comment: yes, `$query` is already processed query variable with respect to admin i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wotking on wp front-end and reach similar feauture you are requested

The code you provide are woking current on wp-admin page but any one uses that code prevent his own SuperAdmin account form reviewing other editors posts .
    just add `!is_super_admin()` to your first contition like this :-

`if($query->is_admin &&  !is_super_admin()   )`

BTW the author's ID  are already provided with `global $user_ID;`
and when you add this `$query->set('author',$user_ID);` the main query will filter posts result accurding to author ID , see [`WP_Query();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

See this-

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89990/how-we-can-get-the-author-id-by-its-name

And, a better way to get posts by an author would be-

```
get_posts('author'=>AUTHOR_ID);
```